# Use Gstreamer in Python to read and save video from camera stream with access to buffer

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am a beginner in Gstreamer, but I managed to build two pipelines to read and save to file a number of camera streams and use them in Python. Currently I am using OpenCV VideoCapture and VideoWriter to do the job, but I need access also to the Gstreamer buffer to retrieve the frame timestamp as I will need to synchronize the captured frames with another process. I was told that once the frame is read in VideoCapture then the timestamp information is lost, so my question is how can I access the frame buffer with the pipeline that I built?

This is the code that I have at the moment, reading and writing streams from four cameras. I used OpenCV because it worked so far but it is not essential, if the conversion to BGR and CV frame can be skipped then I'll be happy too.

```
import cv2

def gstreamer_in(cam_id):
    """ Creates string with gstreamer input pipeline """
    gst_in =  ('nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id={} ! ' 
    'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), height=1080, width=1920, framerate=(fraction)30/1, format=NV12 ! ' 
    'nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, height=1080, width=1920, format=BGRx ! '
    'videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! '
    'appsink').format(cam_id)
    return gst_in


def gstreamer_out(cam_id):
    """ Creates string with gstreamer output pipeline """
    gst_out =('appsrc ! autovideoconvert ! '
    'omxh265enc ! video/x-h265, stream-format=byte-stream ! '
    'h265parse ! filesink location=video_{}.h265 ').format(cam_id)
    return gst_out


n_cams = 4
caps = []
writers=[]

for i in range(0,n_cams):
    # Create VideoCapture and writers
    caps.append(cv2.VideoCapture(gstreamer_in(i), cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER))
    writers.append(cv2.VideoWriter(gstreamer_out(i), cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, i, 30, (1920, 1080), True))


print("Press q to stop...")

while True:
    # Read and write cameras
    for i in range(0, n_cams):
        ret, frame = caps[i].read()
        # read timestamp?
        if ret == True:
            writers[i].write(frame)
    
    # other process happening here

    if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q'):
        break

# Release
for i in range(0, n_cams):
    caps[i].release()
    writers[i].release()
```

Comment: I believe you should use Python gstreamer library instead of OpenCV

Comment: @alercelik Thank you for your input. I'm not actively working on this issue anymore. I tried the gstreamer library as you suggested and I was able to read the timestamp, but unfortunately in that way the performance when recording was worse so I couldn't use it